# Can Spring's Retryable or RetryTemplate use Retry-After header for dynamic backoff?

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

Can I make Spring's @Retryable or @RetryTemplate use the number received in a `Retry-After` header in an HTTP `503` "Service Unavailable" response as delay for the next retry iteration?

For example:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 42,
           backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),
           value = NotYetReady.class)
public boolean isExternalComponentReadyToUse() throws NotYetReady {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = callRestEndpointToCheckReadiness();
    if (!response.getStatus().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        int retryAfterInSeconds = response.getHeaders().get("Retry-After");
        // tell @Retryable to run next attempt after retryAfterInSeconds?
        throw new NotYetReady();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Our Java app relies on an external component that takes some minutes to come up. That component provides a REST endpoint to check readiness. The endpoint sends back `503` with a `Retry-After` header if it can estimate how long the remaining setup will take.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>One way would be to store the value in a static `ThreadLocal` (e.g. `MyHolder.setDelay(...)`) and use `delayExpression` in the `@Backoff()` to retrieve that value.</strike>

Something like `"T(com.foo.MyHolder).getDelay()"`.

You would need to wire up a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` as a `@Bean` with a custom `BackoffPolicy` and reference it in the `@Retryable.interceptor` property.

Comment: Actually; that won't work - the expression is only evaluated once - when the annotation is parsed. Sorry. You would have to wire up a custom interceptor and use the `interceptor` property.