# With Spring Retry, is it possible to pass the backoff value as a function parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-retry

Currently I'm using the following annotation to control backoff and retry parameters.

```
@Retryable(value = { RemoteCallException.class },
            maxAttemptsExpression = "{@Properties.getRetries()}",
            backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "{@Properties.getBackoff()}"))
```

However, I have a lot of different Rest calls in my code and I would like the function caller to be able to specify a backoff at runtime instead of being constrained to specify at initialization time. Is this possible? I'm trying to avoid a sleep statement in the @Recover function since I want to use the backoff that's built into the Spring Retry API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible; the expression is evaluated once only, during initialization.

Coincidently, I opened a [new feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/184) for this a few days ago.

You can do it with a custom retry policy wired into a custom interceptor and passed in the `@Retry` via the `interceptor` property.

See my [SO answer linked in that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559733/can-springs-retryable-or-retrytemplate-use-retry-after-header-for-dynamic-backo/58560029#58560029) for a bit more detail about how to do that.

Comment: Could I edit the retry template for the class with every function call with a new BackoffPolicy?

Comment: No; not if you have multiple concurrent callers. You need a custom policy, perhaps using a `ThreadLocal` to store the actual policy you want to use for that call.